# learning python the hard way exercise 17

Tags: python

Getting too many values to unpack from line 4 in module.

```
script, from_file, to_file = argv  line.
```

exercise 17 example

```
 from sys import argv
 from os.path import exists

 script, from_file, to_file = argv
```

I know I'm doing something stupid. Using python version 2.7.3

This is verbatim copy and paste from the exercise:

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exist

script, from_file, to_file = argv
```

Ive tried both the solutions and get an Invalid sytax error

Comment: What's the value of `argv` and how are you running the script?

Comment: When in doubt, just do a quick `print argv` or a `print <whatever>` before the line where the error occurs and most of the time you'll easily spot where the problem lies.

Comment: Just tried that and still getting the same error.

Comment: @user2065893 there is no `exist`, there is `exists`. But that shouldn't trigger syntax error. Make sure there are bo weird space. Make them compact. line after line.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the script, you need to provide two command line parameters. Assuming the name of the script is `test.py`, you need to run it as

```
python test.py fromfile.txt tofile.txt
```

Then your variable `script` will equal "test.py",  `from_file` will equal "fromfile.txt" and `to_file` will equal "tofile.txt".

Comment: Gave me an invalid syntax error

Comment: How are you running the script you posted? From command line or from inside some text editor? My solution assumes you run from the command line, otherwise you need to find the "script parameters" option in your editor.

Answer (score 1):

In python you can unpack values like this

```
my_packed_values = ('v1', 'v2', 'v3')
v1, v2, v3 = my_packed_values
print v1
print v2
print v3
```

and you will get `v1`, `v2`, `v3` strings one at a time.

So you can unpacked three values. If you do `v1, v2 = my_packed_values`, you will get that error.

So if `argvs` does not have enough value to unpack (the number on the right side does not match the number of left side), you will get too many to unpack.

This is not an answer, but while writing this answer @mbatchkarvo already pointed out the actual cause.

---

There is `os.path.exists`, not `os.path.exist`. But this shouldn't trigger syntax error.

Comment: Thanks trying to Implement this logic presently.

Comment: Now I'm getting cannot import name exist

Comment: @user2065893 see my comment and edit. you write `exits` not `exist`. just add `s` at the end of the word. you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

my advice always do some error checking when processing command line args, eg. at least something simple like

```
from sys import argv,exit
if not len(argv)==3:
   print "argv is" , argv
   print "expected script fromfile tofile"
   exit()
script, from_file, to_file = argv
```

alternately, or perhaps more pythonesque:

```
from sys import argv,exit
try:
   script, from_file, to_file = argv
except:
   print "argv is" , argv
   print "expected script fromfile tofile"
   exit()
```

note the import of exit from sys

Comment: Where do I add the error checking lines?